# Update progressbar for each item found

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have an issue with my progressbar and my loops (on C#).
I need to parse a collection of items (via a foreach loop), and for each object found I need to increment a progress bar (through a for loop)... But my code runs for each object found, what it is normal, but I can not find a workaround...

Here is my simplified code :

```
int totalSteps = lv_selection.Items.Count;

        foreach (string p in lv_selection.Items)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < totalSteps; i++)
            {
                // A time consuming job
                (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress((int)(100 / totalSteps) * i, null);

                // Update the progressbar's text (located in another form)
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    progressbarForm.Progress(p);
                });
            }
        }
```

The progressbar progress as expected, but for each item in my collection ("p" variable). I understand why, but i'm don't know how to fix that.

Also tryed to interchange the for and foreach loops. And set the for loop after the "time consuming job".

Is anyone could help me please?

Thank's a lot.

Comment: If "The progressbar progress as expected" then what is your question? I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: What exactly is a "progress bar"? what technology is this? MVC, WPF, Winforms, Xamarin??!

Comment: Apologize, I maybe mis explained :) I meant the progressbar fill correctly, but it starts again for each item found. If I have 4 items in my collection, the progressbar will fill 4 times. It's a WPF ProgressBar, managed in c# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it ! :)

I tried to use a trick, and it works fine.

I create an integer variable before the foreach, set to 0. Inside the foreach, i increment this variable by one, and send his value to my progressbar as a step.

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        int totalSteps = lv_selection.Items.Count;
        int currentStep = 0;

        // Installations
        foreach (string p in lv_selection.Items)
        {
            currentStep++;

            // My long task 

            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                progressbarForm.Progress(p);
            });

            (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress((int)(100 / totalSteps) * currentStep, null);

            }
    }
```